# How do I generate machine code with LLVM's new PassManager API?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm working on a project and would prefer to use LLVM's new API with specializations of LLVM::PassManager. I tried looking at llc's code, but it uses the legacy PassManager. Is there a way to do it with the new API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is currently WIP. Patches are welcome :)